# database design question - null foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is a trucking app that is tracking expenses. I am a noob on the back-end and still learning database design.

I want to be able to filter it in the front-end by either the type of expense(truck,trailer,general) and also by the individual truck or trailer
So here I would want to be able to just view only truck expenses, or all the expenses related only to truck #t777.

```
type  | reference  |  category    |  amount   |   date     |    
truck    t777         tires          $1,200       4-21-2019
truck    t777         inspection       $250       4-21-2019
truck    t777         heating/ac       $800       4-21-2019
truck    t4555        tires          $1,205       4-21-2019
trailer  p594         floor          $2,200       4-21-2019
general  null         tax/license    $7,000       4-11-2019
```

One expense will belong to either truck,trailer or general.( only one)
One truck can have many expenses
One trailer can have many expenses
general expense can have many expenses.

From what I have read, it is ok for the fk to be null, but is there a better way to design this ? 

I simplified the tables for less clutter.
[image]

```
tbl Truck
id

tbl Trailer
id

tbl General
id

tb Expenses<br>
id PK <br>
truck_id ( null) FK<br>
trailer_id ( null) FK<br>
general_id ( null) FK
```

Comment: Your database model translates your reality and requirements into relational logic. To check if your translation is correct and/or propose a different approach, we need to know what it is suppose to describe. There are certainly situations where this model fits perfectly. Although I doubt it is the case here, we cannot help you without more details, e.g. a list of requirements like "I want to be able to track expenses per delivery.", "An expense is usually for truck and trailer combined (e.g. toll?)", "A delivery uses one truck and up to 2 trailers", ideally minimalized to a single problem.

Comment: @Solarflare, I see i didnt provide much of the context. I updated my post, I hope that gives a better picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: A NULL in a foreign key (or part of a foreign key) generally means that the relationship is optional,  and is omitted in this instance.  This is a frequent practice,  and it generally works pretty well.  To see whether it's good design in your case,  consider two things:  what happens when you do a join using the foreign key, and what happens when you do a group by?  If, when you do a join, the entries with NULLs in them drop out, and that's what you want, all well and good.  Some DBMSes drop entries with NULLS out of all groups.  If you get what you want,  all well and good.

Comment: When a FK gets in the way, abandon it.  Note:  A FK does 2 things: a dynamic data-integrity check (you should not have any flaws in your code, so this is redundant); and provides an index for performance (which you can manually add).

Answer (score 1):

There is one technique you might consider.  It's called Shared Primary Key.  You can look it up.

In this case, you need a fourth table, called Vehicle (for lack of a better name).  It has just one field,  ID.  The ID fields in Truck, Trailer, and General are copies of the corresponding ID in Vehicle.  There three ID fields are declared to be both PKs and FKs that reference the Vehicle table.  You have to do a little extra programming for the case when you insert a new vehicle.

Now, you can get away with just one field, Vehicle_Id, as an FK in Expenses.

You can add a type field to the Vehicle table if it helps you manage the data, but you can get away without it.